# How accurate is Delphi's 'Now' timestamp

Tags: delphi, timestamp

I'm going to be working on a project that will require (fairly) accurate time-stamping of incoming RS232 serial and network data from custom hardware. As the data will be coming from a number of independant hardware sources, I will need to timestamp all data so it can be deskewed/ interpolated to a nominal point in time.

My immediate though was just to use the inbuilt Now command to timestamp, however a quick Google seems to indicate that this is only going to be accurate to around 50 msecs or so.

Unfortunately, the more I read the more confused I become. There seems to be a lot of conflicting advice on GetTickCount and QueryPerformanceCounter, with complications due to todays multicore processors and CPU throttling. I have also seen posts recommending using the Windows multimedia timers, but I cannot seem to find any code snippets to do this.

So, can anyone advise me:

1) How accurate 'Now' will be.

2) Whether there is a simple, higher accuracy alternative.

Note: I would be hoping to timestamp to within, say , 10 milliseconds, and i am not looking for a timer as such, just a better time-stamping method. This will be running on a Windows 7 32 bit low-power micro-PC. I will be using either Delphi XE or Delphi 2007, if it makes any difference.

Comment: The latency you get in storing any data is going to far outweigh the accuracy of the system clock, isn't it? Even if you run each connection in a separate thread, receiving data/storing it/getting the next data point is going to far exceed 50ms, IMO. (IIRC, the latency of the clock timer in Windows is around 18ms, so I doubt you can get a timestamp of more granularity than that using the system clock anyway.) The high frequency counters can get more granular (as the linked link at the top of the "related* list to the right shows) is more granular, but they're slow to execute. (@TLama's link.)

Comment: This may help: http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007_11_01_archive.html Don't miss the part at the end about windows versions starting with Vista.

Comment: This question made me think of [How soon is Now?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Soon_Is_Now%3F)

Comment: Since all standard methods (getTickCount, timers) are not accurate enough for your needs (I guess) you should switch to performance counters.
eventually combine it with now... e.g.

Comment: Don't make me play Morrissey at you, Heffernan. Life's a Pigsty.

Comment: For simple alternatives with higher accuracy: a GPS or Radio Clock or connection to a NTP service. See [`Accurate Time Keeping on your PC using NTP`](http://www.satsignal.eu/software/ntp.htm).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to documentation, [Now](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.Now) is as accurate only to the nearest second:

> Although TDateTime values can represent milliseconds, Now is accurate only to the nearest second.

Despite this, looking at the current implementation, Now is as accurate as the [GetLocalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338(v=vs.85).aspx) windows API could be.

Making a quick test, it shows Now returns values for each millisecond in the clock, for example:

```
begin
  System.SysUtils.FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat := 'hh:mm:ss.zzz';
  for I := 1 to 5000 do
    Writeln(TimeToStr(Now()));
end.
```

When I executed this console program from the command line `project1 >times.txt`, in a Windows 7 64 bits machine, I got a file that goes along 29 milliseconds continually (no one is missing in the file).

You have to face the fact that running in a Windows environment, your application/thread may get processor slices with varying time in between, depending on how busy is the system and the priority of your application/threads versus all the other threads running in the system.

Comment: To be a little more discrete, you'll find `GetLocalTime` to be accurate to 55ms on 9x OS, 10.0144ms (single core non-HT machines), 15.625ms (multi-core, multi-CPU, HT machines) on 2K and XP (as accurate as `GetTickCount` up to Vista), 1ms on Vista and later (different from GetTickCount).

Comment: Nice finding, of course it depends on the OS and the MS documentation have no info about precision.

Comment: Indeed. That information only depends on web search and personal tests. One of the articles I find valuable is Gabr's [blog entry](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2007_11_01_archive.html).

Comment: Thanks all. The documentation is a little lacking. I realise that Windows may not be the ideal operation system for such a controller, however user familiarity is important. Happily it is a dedicated PC, so I will be able to control the load and should be able to specify the processor, so all the information provided is very useful.